# aws-sdk-cpp exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable

Tags: c++, boost, aws-sdk-cpp

I have problem with integration of aws-sdk-cpp with boost and any exception handling.

As soon I linked in cmakelists aws-cpp-sdk-s3 compiler became very strict: errors per unused param, exception handling disabled. I have no idea how I can configure it. Can't find anything in documentation.

Comment: I am having the same issue trying to use boost and aws-sdk-cpp-dynamodb together within a CMake build system.

Comment: I was having a great holidays for the last month, until I got a notification on stack, about new comment in some topic I've totally forgot. This reminded me of a mess that I left behind that is going to haunt me in next weeks. -_-

Comment: @Beirdo: does it work properly on standard g++ compilation?

Comment: Yes, it does.  My solution so far (which I don't like much) is to use cmake/make on the SDK, the install it to the system in /usr/local.  Then I pointed the other cmake setup to it as a system library so it doesn't use the pkg-config file, which seems to be how the CXXFLAGS are modified.

Comment: The other thing are those compilation restrictions. How do you surpress no exception handling during compilation with aws-cpp-sdk?

Comment: You don't need to.  That code doesn't use exceptions, so I compile it as they have it setup...  With -fno-exceptions.  Then when I compile boost and my code, I use -fexceptions, and link in the SDK as a library.  I could have hacked on the SDK and changed it to -fexceptions and it would still be fine, it would just add handlers that will never be called.  At least that's my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. When i changed the line

```
find_package(aws-sdk-cpp)
```

to

```
find_package(AWSSDK REQUIRED)
```

everything worked fine. Not sure why this works, but it seems to work!